Unterminated String Error When Cloning a Promo Component in SXA on Sitecore 10.4
We cloned the SXA promo component in Sitecore 10.4 and modified the datasource template along with other basic settings. However, when adding the component to a page, we encounter an "Unterminated string" error.

Note: No custom code was added; it's purely a content component we're creating, and there is nothing in the logs.

can you please check Is there any error in console.

@olive can you also please share the error details you get, when you click on the Details button in the popup.

The "Unterminated string" error typically occurs when a closing quotation mark is missing in a string. Additionally, when you drag and drop the component, a pop-up should appear to select the datasource. It seems there might be an issue with your datasource location or the datasource template field at the rendering level.
Are you using any datasource query for the datasource location? If so, please review or modify it and check if that resolves the issue, as no other changes have been made.
Also, please share the logs and console logs from the Experience Editor to investigate further.
Let me know if this works!

The "Unterminated string" error can occur in different scenarios. In my case, it was due to an issue with the datasource template. Here are a few areas to check for a cloned component:

Datasource Template Changes: If the modified datasource template
includes fields that are incorrectly referenced in the rendering
code (e.g., missing quotation marks or incorrect JSON structure), it
might cause this error.
View Rendering/JavaScript Modifications: If you've made changes to
the view rendering or added custom JavaScript, ensure there are no
syntax issues, especially with strings and concatenation.
Rendering Parameters: Ensure that any parameters passed to the
component are correctly formatted and escaped, particularly when
working with strings or JSON data.
Presentation Details: Verify that the component's rendering settings
are correct. Make sure the assigned views, controllers, or models
match the updated datasource template structure.

Lastly, don't forget to check the error logs and console logs in the Experience Editor to get more insights.
Hope this helps

I tried to clone the Promo component in the Sitecore 10.4 version and it works perfectly without any error. Here is the screenshot.

As you mentioned you have not done any kind of modification to the code, so seems like there is some issue with the modification of the datasource template along with other basic settings.
Since you modified the data source template, make sure that the fields you've added or modified are correctly handled in the rendering code. Missing fields or incorrect field types could lead to unexpected issues.
Finally, open your browser's developer tools (F12) and check the console for any detailed error messages or stack traces that could give more context on where the issue is occurring.
Hope this helps.
